# MySQL Query Only Return One Row

Tags: php, mysql

Any ideas why this query only return a single row?

```
SELECT c.category_id, c.parent_id, cd.name, cd.description 
FROM mydb_category c 
LEFT JOIN mydb_category_description cd 
ON (c.category_id = cd.category_id) 
WHERE c.category_id IN ('46,59') 
AND c.status        = '1' 
AND cd.language_id  = '1'
```

The `language_id` is correct, the `status` is correct, but for some reason I'm only getting the row with `category_id` 46 returned.

Comment: Try `WHERE c.category_id IN (46,59) ` without the quotes

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Can one of you guys explain why quotes stop the query from continuing?

Comment: You're creating a string `'46,59'` which the query tries to match as one of the `IN` conditions.

Comment: because with quotes c.category_id is compared with string `'46,59'`

Comment: Is anyone else concerned that this even returned 1 result.

Comment: I assumed the answer was because it was be interpreted as a string, but I wonder as a string, why was any of it matched. As @Orangepill said, why was it even returning one result. Weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the quotes in `IN('46,49')` so your query look like this:

```
SELECT 
    c.category_id, c.parent_id, cd.name, cd.description
FROM
    mydb_category c
        LEFT JOIN
    mydb_category_description cd ON (c.category_id = cd.category_id)
WHERE
    c.category_id IN (46,59)
        AND c.status = '1'
        AND cd.language_id = '1'
```

Se the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) for more info. Good luck!